# Anything below top half of page displays in black & white on print preview in browser

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net, browser, printing

I'm working on an old site and when trying to print reports the css styling doesn't appear on anything below the first half of the page.
There are two tables per report and it might have something to do with this, as the first table displays colour when in print preview whereas the second table does not.

The site utilises VB and ASPX, and I believe the site was originally created use Microsoft Word, so this might be important.

Comment: Images in the report display in colour, whereas any styling for text in the second table isnt displayed. - the styling is needed as the report is colour coded due to priority.

Comment: Browsers nowadays tend to have tools built in to help you find out where CSS is going wrong.

Comment: The report displays fine on screen, just not when in print preview or when printing.
Using Chromes inspect element there doesnt seem to be any conflicting styles. And there isn't a specific style for print in the CSS files either

Comment: Have you tried using a different printer driver, e.g. Microsoft XPS Document Writer (if you're using Windows)? Does the problem persist across different browsers?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Unfortunately it's the same with different drivers and also the same across different browsers